# remote osx split panes in ubuntu byobu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, osx, tmux, byobu

### My Problem

I have OSX 10.10, connect to a byobu in ubuntu 14.04 over ssh.

I want to split panes vertically & horizontally.

But ctrl+F2 & shift+F2 just gives me beep sound.

### Additional Info

ctrl-a-|, ctrl-a-S won't work either.

I am using Terminal.app, xterm-256color.

byobu-ctrl-a is set to screen.

F1~F9(without modifier keys) works fine. But F10~F12 just gives me '~' in the terminal.

I tried setting another keymap. But I was not sure I got it right. Add below into ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf

```
unbind '"'
bind - splitw -v # vertical split (prefix -)
unbind %
bind | splitw -h # horizontal split (prefix |)
```

It's really exhausting trying to figure out how all the byobu & tmux config files work together.

Comment: BTW, if you have mouse support working in this environment, I'd be interested to hear about it. I've been struggling on it for days: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275693/diagnose-mouse-problems-in-byobu-already-added-tmux-conf-not-working

Answer (score 0):

OS-X is a little tricky as I found out the hard way.

1. The function keys are hidden behind the Fn (but I'm guessing you already found that since you said they work unmodified)
2. Most of the function keys with the Fn applied are already assigned to other functions. Visit the Keyboard Shortcuts in System Prefs to fix these.

What I have done is:

1. Reverted to using Fn keys as Function Keys. ie, in System Prefs I've told OS-X to not use them as built in features (volume, brightness, mission control et al) and use them as function keys specifically. See https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204436
2. I have then gone to and removed all associated shortcuts that are assigned to function keys in the Keyboard shortcuts area. They were used for things I just don't use anyway.

The only functionality I really miss quick and easy access to is the volume keys, especially mute for when something unexpectedly arcs up pretty loud, but other than that, when I hit a brightness key, I'll hit it once or twice then realise and add the Fn and get it done.

This has helped me not only in byobu but in other non standard OS-X stuff such as Chrome Extensions that use function keys and nothing specific to OS-X. Now these function perfectly as required